# RoR Gem for Creating & Receiving Emails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, email

I would like to create a feature where a user can send an e-mail and the text of that email is posted on the user's web page (we're using devise for account management).

Any guidance about how we would go about building this, gems to use, et cetera?

Thanks

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a variety of ways you can do this, but the cheapest is probably using [Mailman](https://github.com/mailman/mailman).

You have to set up an SMTP server, but thats not too difficult, and then you can basically follow the [mailman user guide](https://github.com/mailman/mailman/blob/master/USER_GUIDE.md)

If you don't want to have to manage your own mail server, or are having issues with spam/outgoing mails being marked as spam, your best bet is to use one of the email services out there.

I've had good luck with Mailgun, which has a transactional incoming email API, which is exactly what you want.

They have a fairly easy to follow getting started guide:

https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-receiving.html

And a good gem as well, for their HTTP api:

https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby

If you don't like mailgun for whatever reason, there are several other services out there, such as Mandrill by Mailchimp, Sendgrid, and Amazon SNS/SES.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very clear description of your question. I guess the main purpose is to just sending mail use ruby, the mail [gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail) is there, and it is also the base that Rails ActionMail built on.